# spring boot external config property file not loading when running under non root users

Tags: spring-boot

One way to make the spring boot app load the external property file is to put it under a folder called **config**. This folder has to be where the **jar** file is located and I figured in only works when I **CD** to this path to run the ***java -jar your_app.jar*** command. 
I have tried this and it works fine, but I need to run the command under a different user so I am using something like ***su - user_name -c "java -jar your_app.jar"*** and for some reason it stops loading the external property file when running the app with su command. 
I have tried to change the ownership of all the related paths/files to that specific **user_name** but it did not help.
Any one who has more spring boot experience might be able to help me.

Comment: Can you post your real attempts here?

Answer (score 0):

removed the first dash (-) and it works fine.
was `su - user_name -c "java -jar your_app.jar"`
changed to `su user_name -c "java -jar your_app.jar"`